# Link broken when you receive a moderator message

Tags: bug, ios-app

When a moderator has tried to contact you, it appears like this in the app notifications (first pic). But then when you click on it, it goes there (second pic).

The notification now disappears (is no longer highlighted), you shrug and say "Well I guess it wasn't that important anyway..." and get on with your life.

*Note:* the link is actually OK (I checked outside of the app), but if you're not authenticated outside the app then I guess this should redirect you to a login page instead of just 404 error.

[image: Img1]

[image: Sadface]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it's deliberate. All pages, whether you're logged in or not that you try to access and don't have permissions for will 404. There's no "link might be valid and request auth" anywhere.

Comment: Yeah... If I go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/674039 - you can see that and it exists for every user on the site. If you browse anonymously you get a 404 and no actual challenge to confirm existence except just signing in top right on the navbar.

Comment: So you are not logged-in but can still access your inbox.  Hmm.  I can think of a better fix for that :)

Comment: I am authenticated.  In the *app*.  So either the app should be able to open the message, or it shouldn't be notifying me about it, but when you click it and it's opening the moderator message in the device's browser (where I'm not authenticated) that's like the worst of both worlds.

Comment: So... The app can't pass across credentials or valid tokens into another process and by design access to any valid link where the user doesn't have permission will 404. Probably the same reason deleted questions for non 10k users just 404 as well instead of presenting a login.

Comment: The app has never been able to independently show you inbox messages. It might have been on the roadmap and a feature request somewhere - however, it's never been a priority and sadly I don't think any further work will be happening on it in the near future [citation needed]

Comment: Yes, I understand, but if I wasn't a web developer myself I would just assume the message was a mistake.  And then three minutes later I would forget about this "moderator message".  If the mods ever want to say anything important, it's not a good bug to have.

Comment: I think the app could be great and the effort that's gone in to it shouldn't be shrugged off. Having said that, I've only used it for notifications - everything else I use the mobile browser for.

Comment: Ahhh... Ok. So more a practical standpoint then - if you'd not been so diligent - you might just have thought  
 "bah... Can't read that - let's move on"?

Comment: (You should have got a copy of the message to your registered email address anyway but that's not quite here or there).

Comment: *sigh* I never was worthy of a moderator messages :/

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You don't always get moderator messages for the best of reasons...

Comment: @Félix Need one? :p

Comment: @BhargavRao That'd be an honor, but might leave a slight on my account history ;)